# Problems with libblkid

Tags: mount, updates, uuid

This message showed a lot of times:

```
udevadm: /usr/local/lib/libuuid.so.1: no version information available (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libblkid.so.1)
```

or this:

```
blkid: /usr/local/lib/libuuid.so.1: no version information available (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libblkid.so.1)
```

It happens when I run, for example kernel update and as a result I cannot make full update:

```
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.125ubuntu6.3) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-30-generic
blkid: /usr/local/lib/libuuid.so.1: no version information available (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libblkid.so.1)
blkid: /usr/local/lib/libuuid.so.1: no version information available (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libblkid.so.1)
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/fsck failed with return 1.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-30-generic with 1.
dpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
```

Also this message shows when I run `mount` command, etc - a lot of times.
Any ideas?

Comment: How did you come to have a `libuuid.so.1` in `/usr/local/lib`? That's not a place where such libraries would live, by default - have you installed any software from source?

Comment: Thank you! Yes, possible I've installed some software from sources times ago, but I've noticed what exactly caused this error. I've removed dublicates of `libuuid.so.1` in `/usr/local/lib` and everything works now.